# Making a scatterplot in PowerBI

Tags: tableau-api, powerbi, scatter

I'm used to using Tableau (similar to powerBI), and I'm now testing powerBI as well. I've been trying to receate a plot from Tableau, but I'm unable to do it (see the images).

Now I realize that this probably has a very simple solution, and I understand the general problem with how the data is aggregated together, but I'm just not able to find the solution on my own. What sort of buttons should I push in PowerBI to make this work?

Thanks for any help!

Tableau plot
[image]

PowerBI plot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Tableau plot, you're putting the Date at **Day** level on the x-axis. In the PowerBI plot, you've the Date at **Year** level at the the x-axis. That's why all points are displayed exactly on a year.

You should put the Day at Day level on the x-axis in the PowerBI plot, just like the Tableau plot. You can do this by dragging the date column in the X Axis field, and remove the Year, Quarter and Month level. The only remaining level will be Day.

Edit:

Or don't display the hierarchy, and display the date field:

[image: 'Hierachy vs. Date]

Comment: Sorry I messed up a comment. Changing to DAY gives me an equally useless graph: https://imgur.com/a/Wlyym And changing from Date Hierarchy just gives me the original graph with the years again.

Comment: Yes, I see what's going wrong. In this case, I think PowerBI can't produce the same graph. If you set it to Day, you'll have the detail you want, but only per year. If you set it to Year, you'll have all the years, but not the detail at day level. But showing the years on the axis, and putting the numbers on day level.. that's not possible I believe. Maybe you can make the graph a bit wider, and put the Year-Month (new column like 01-2016) on the axis? Then you'll have 12 points between the years. I know, not the best solution.

Comment: There has to be some way to do this properly in PowerBI. It's super easy to achieve in Tableau. I'm gonna try to ask at some other forums as well. Thanks a lot for your help though!

Comment: Please let us know when you find an answer, very curious! The community at powerbi.com is very active. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

## Change the Date field from "Date Hierarchy" to plain "Date"

Power BI treats dates as hierarchies by default - this is useful for *drilling* (e.g. see the "big picture" of year-over-year performance, and than drill down to month or day resolution) in interactive reports, but less so when you just need a quick summary.

You can change this using the dropdown button next to the "date" field in the visual's field-well. Just choose "**Date**" instead of "**Date Hierarchy**":

[image: The visual with date as values]

For comparison, this is the same visual with date as date hierarchy:
[image: The visual with date as a hierarchy]

There are some additional details in this [5 Minutes BI](https://5minutebi.com/2017/11/29/how-to-use-powerbi-date-hierarchy/) blog post.